# How do I install Redshift 1.12 on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon from source?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, compiling, redshift

### Redshift

packages which are available in most distributions are dated 2016-01-02, which is > 2.5 years ago.

Like on my system - Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 64-bit - there is only [1.11 version](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/releases/tag/v1.11) available:

```
$ apt-cache policy redshift
redshift:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.11-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.11-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Note, that Linux Mint 19 is based on the latest Ubuntu 18.04.

That might be caused by too little commits made in [version 1.12](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/releases/tag/v1.12).

Either way, I personally find [version 1.12](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/releases/tag/v1.12) it a rather crucial step forward.

---

### Question

Anyway, my question is, how to install the newer version without adding any PPA?

Let me re-phrase. How do I install [Redshift 1.12](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/releases/tag/v1.12) on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon from source?

Please do include basic settings and set-up as I am not yet familiar with its settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’re on a Debian derivative, you can rebuild the packaged sources of version 1.12:

```
cd ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}
sudo apt install devscripts debian-keyring
dget -x http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/redshift/redshift_1.12-2.dsc
cd redshift-1.12
sudo apt build-dep redshift
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
sudo dpkg -i ../redshift{,-gtk}_1.12-2_*.deb
```

There are a number of advantages over installing from source directly:

- you don’t need to purge the existing packages;
- the updated software is still managed by the package management system;
- future upgrades to the package will be applied without needing to rebuild again (or uninstall the manually-installed software and installing the package).

If the configuration needs to be re-visited, see [Vlastimil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/126755/vlastimil)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473588/86440) for details.

Answer (score 2):

## Compilation

**You can skip this section if you are experienced, as you won't find anything new here.**

First, we need to purge the old version from the system.

When compiling, I always purge instead of removal, because usually, some paths will change.

```
sudo apt-get purge redshift redshift-gtk
```

Then, we prepare for the compilation. Luckily, in this case, it can be done simply with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep redshift-gtk
```

probably because the dependencies did not change since the last packaged version.

Now, we need the source code, I always create a new folder for a compiled program, so:

```
mkdir redshift && cd redshift
```

Followed by the download of the source code:

```
wget https://github.com/jonls/redshift/releases/download/v1.12/redshift-1.12.tar.xz
```

And unpacking the archive, while, again, going directly into the created directory:

```
tar -xJf redshift-1.12.tar.xz && cd redshift-1.12
```

Let's run `configure` script with appropriate switches:

```
./configure # --enable-gui --enable-ubuntu
```

On a side note, while the `--enable-gui` was enabled by default, it did not enable the `--enable-ubuntu` by default on my Linux Mint, which I believe it should. However, I see no difference, anyways. So, the default configuration is probably ok.

Just compile it then:

```
make
```

---

### Configuration

You will have to manually create the configuration directory as it's moved in this version, though falling back in case the directory does not exist:

```
mkdir ~/.config/redshift
```

Use your favorite text editor to create and edit the config file, I will use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) here:

```
code ~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf
```

---

Example config file heavily commented.

```
; Global settings file for Redshift application.
[redshift]


; The location provider for solar elevation.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue2' or 'manual'.
; The actual provider settings are in a separate section.
location-provider=manual


; Smooth fade between temperatures when Redshift starts and stops.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; - 0 will cause an immediate change between screen temperatures.
; - 1 will gradually apply the new screen temperature over a couple of seconds.
fade=0


; Solar elevation thresholds.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; By default, Redshift will use the current elevation of the sun to determine
; whether it is daytime, night or in transition (dawn / dusk). When the sun is
; above the degrees specified with elevation-high it is considered daytime and
; below elevation-low it is considered night.
;elevation-high=3
;elevation-low=-6


; Day and night screen temperatures.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Default temperatures:
; - Day time  : 6500K
; - Night time: 4500K
temp-day=6000
temp-night=4500


; Custom dawn / dusk times.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Instead of using the solar elevation, the time intervals of dawn and dusk can
; be specified manually. The times must be specified as HH:MM in 24-hour format.
dawn-time=00:00
dusk-time=15:00


; The adjustment method: 'randr', 'vidmode'.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; This has changed since the 1.12 version in favor of randr
; formerly vidmode has mostly been used from what I read.
adjustment-method=randr


; Manual GPS of the location for solar elevation.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Standard longitude and latitude coordinates.
[manual]
lat=00.8111306
; EDIT THIS ^^
lon=00.1414300
; EDIT THIS ^^


; Adjustment method settings.
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so 1 is actually the second screen.
; This actually works for all monitors, needs clarification!
[randr]
screen=0
```

---

### Installation

I recommend trying out the compiled version before actually installing it.

For some reason, the compiled GTK binary is not made executable, so to try it out:

```
chmod u+x ./src/redshift-gtk/redshift-gtk
./src/redshift-gtk/redshift-gtk
```

If it works well, then install it with:

```
sudo make install
```