# dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature

Tags: gpg, source-code, signature

System: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon, based on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473606/126755), I am being pointed at a different solution, other than installing directly from source.

Since I haven't ever used `dget`, I must have it installed first with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

---

Upon the first suggested line:

```
$ dget -x http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/redshift/redshift_1.12-2.dsc
```

I originally got **Validation FAILED!!**, which I quickly overcame with creating the following file:

```
~/.devscripts
```

with contents:

```
DSCVERIFY_KEYRINGS="/etc/apt/trusted.gpg:~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx"
```

as pointed out, slightly changed by me, in [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/215008/436624).

And simultaneously importing the public key with:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 402543B2D98854007F627D36A63A58A3F2E17569
```

I get a warning:

> ```
> dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./redshift_1.12-2.dsc
> ```

---

The whole command output follows:

```
dget: retrieving http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/redshift/redshift_1.12-2.dsc
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   328  100   328    0     0   2466      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2466
100  2180  100  2180    0     0   8549      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8549
dget: retrieving http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/redshift/redshift_1.12.orig.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   334  100   334    0     0    865      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   865
100  474k  100  474k    0     0   666k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2597k
dget: retrieving http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/redshift/redshift_1.12-2.debian.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   338  100   338    0     0    840      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   840
100  5720  100  5720    0     0  11793      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11793
redshift_1.12-2.dsc:
      Good signature found
   validating redshift_1.12.orig.tar.xz
   validating redshift_1.12-2.debian.tar.xz
All files validated successfully.
gpgv: Signature made Tue 02 Oct 2018 12:40:08 PM CEST
gpgv:                using RSA key 402543B2D98854007F627D36A63A58A3F2E17569
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./redshift_1.12-2.dsc
dpkg-source: info: extracting redshift in redshift-1.12
dpkg-source: info: unpacking redshift_1.12.orig.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking redshift_1.12-2.debian.tar.xz
```

---

At this point, I am out of ideas where the warning is coming from? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure if this is *the right* solution to my problem, but since it resolved the warning, I will add it here:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring
```

---

As pointed out by [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt), there is another possibility to disable verification with:

```
dget -x -u ...
```

but the above approach is better from the security standpoint.

Comment: I'd say installing `debian-keyring` is certainly the right solution in this case. That package contains the keys of all Debian developers and maintainers, who you already trust since you are running a Debian derivative distribution. If instead the package comes from Ubuntu you may need to install `ubuntu-keyring`. Don't disable code signature verification.